# Can't connect to WordPress multisite db on AWS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, multisite

I have an EC2 instance on AWS where I've set up a LAMP server to host a WordPress multisite. I'm now trying to transfer my local environment to AWS. Everything runs smoothly transfering files and uploading the db through Sequel Pro. When I try and access the site I keep getting a connection error.

- Have searched and replaced all instances of my local environment's url with the IP of my E2 instance.
- Tried using DB_HOST (WP Config) as localhost, AWS IP, and AWS DNS
- Set up WP Config with AWS credentials

If I use localhost I seem to be able to connect half-way, I end up with this message at /wp-admin,

"Could not find site **52.17.182.78**. Searched for table **wp_blogs** in database **example**. Is that right?"

The IP is listed in wp_blogs. Server is set up with standard SSH access. WordPress version 4.1.2. Any ideas?

Comment: have you edit your .config file.

Comment: you have to chane database name, dbusername, and dbpassword to config file at root directory of your project ..

Comment: have you changed it ?

Comment: I assume you mean wp_config... Yes, I have changed it to the credentials needed.

Comment: ok then do second step of my answer ...

Comment: I'm having the same troubles. Were you able to find a solution?